# Encontrar valores iguales en dos array PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Estoy trabajando en CodeIgniter estoy llamando a dos `result()` y deseo comprar los datos en la vista.

Modelo

```
public function getallData()
  {
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
    $query = $this->db->get('Data');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
      return $query->result();
    } else { return false; }
  }

    public function getWhere($id)
    {
      $query = $this->db->get_where('Table', array(
        'status' => $id
      ));
      if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
      }
    }
```

Controlador

```
 public function index()
  { $status = 'On';

        $data['datos']=$this->m->getallData();
        $data['tecnicos']=$this->m->getWhere($status);


    $this->load->view('list',$data);

  }
```

Tengo esta vista pero repito los datos :/

```
<?php if ($datos): ?>
    <?php foreach ($datos as $dato): ?>
        <?php foreach ($tecnicos as $tecnico): ?>
         <?php if ($dato-> id == $tecnico-> id_tec): ?>
               <?php echo 'H'; ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Espero haberme explicado bien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede que de lado de la vista, donde tienes incrustado el código PHP la manera en que estás iterando hace falta obtener el valor de cada array, ejemplo:

```
for ($datos as $dato => $valueDato) {....}
```

Y si además deseas recuperar el *dato repetido* sería agregar otro array donde puedas almacenar los valores repetidos, por lo tanto el código quedaría así:

```
$arrayAux = array(10);
$i = 0;
if ($datos) { 
  foreach ($datos as $dato => $valueDato) {
      foreach ($tecnicos as $tecnico => $valueTecnico) {
            if($valueTecnico ==  $valueDato) {
                 if(!in_array($valueTecnico,$arrayAux)) {
                         $arrayAux[$i] =  $valueTecnico;                          
                          $i++; 
                 }    
            }
       }
   }
}
```

Anexo evidencia de que el código es funcional, Saludos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]